# how to use environment variable in docker-compose child Dockerfile FROM clause

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm using docker-compose to build some dockerfiles. I'm using an environment variable `$IMAGE_TAG` to tag images

```
  game-client:
    image: 09809809.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/crashgiants-web:${IMAGE_TAG}
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: devops/client.Dockerfile
      args:
        - IMAGE_TAG=${IMAGE_TAG}
        - SIGNALHUB_HOST=crashgiants.io
        - SOCKETIO_HOST=crashgiants.io
        - TURNSERVER_HOST=crashgiants.io
        - ASSET_HOST=crashgiants.io
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

I have a dockerfile `client.Dockerfile` with a `FROM` clause like:

```
FROM 0809809708.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/crashgiants:$IMAGE_TAG as game-base
```

I can get the environment variable to the docker-compose ok but not sure how to use it within the child `client.Dockerfile`

I am invoking the compose file with: `IMAGE_TAG=local_tester docker-compose -f ./devops/docker-compose.yml build`

This currently throws an error

```
Building game-client

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 126, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 302, in build
  File "compose/project.py", line 468, in build
  File "compose/project.py", line 450, in build_service
  File "compose/service.py", line 1147, in build
compose.service.BuildError: (<Service: game-client>, {'message': 'No build stage in current context'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 78, in main
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str
[95080] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

something about `can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your dockerfile as follows:

```
ARG IMAGE_TAG=latest
FROM 0809809708.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/crashgiants:$IMAGE_TAG as game-base
ARG IMAGE_TAG
```

This will expose the `IMAGE_TAG` as argument to the image. The second `ARG IMAGE_TAG` is if you want to use the argument inside the image build, since the arguments before `FROM` will be in a different context.

Comment: why set `ARG IMAGE_TAG=latest` ? won't that hardcode it to `latest` I want it passed in from the `docker-compose build` environment.